# How to disable sort for a column in CGridView?

Tags: yii, yii-components

There is the `enableSorting` flag, that, if equals false, disable sorting for all grid columns. But how can I do this for just one specific column?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this

```
'sortable'=>false,
```

Here is example ,

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'tasks-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    //'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        array(
        'header'=>'Surname',
        'value'=> '$data->surname',
            'name'=> 'surname',
            'sortable'=>false,
            ),
        'due_date',
        'status',       
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks fellow, but I'm trying exactly the oposite: disable sorting in one column. I achieved this by using `'sortable' => false`. Just correct your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: what if we want to make all column sort able with one liner code?